# Fragments Replacing Fragments and Navigating Fragments usefully

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have this ClientListView that works great, shows clients, I can click on a client and get their details on the right (in my second fragment).  Defined by this layout here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment class="com.viciousbytes.studiotab.subactivities.ClientListView"
        android:id="@+id/client_list" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/client_details" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This works great, but then I realized another activity I had (that was a fragmentactivity displaying a fragment) took up the whole screen, and would be better served being split into two.

So I went about changing some code that displayed this fragment activity originally

```
void showSessionEdit()
{
 ...

 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditSessionActivity.class);
            //  Send the recipe index to the new activity
            intent.putExtra(EditSessionActivity.THE_SELECTED_CLIENT, (int)mClient.getID());
            intent.putExtra(EditSessionActivity.SELECTED_SESSION, sessionId);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1899); 
 ....
}
```

This worked great, brough up my session editor, i click back I get back to my clients and details.  Though I realized I want my session editor to work more like my client list /details which has both on same screen.  Through lots LOTS of trial of error I finally did replaced the above with this:

```
void showSessionEdit()
{
 ...
    SessionEdit details = (SessionEdit) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.session_edit);               
                // Make new fragment instance to show the recipe
                details = SessionEdit.newInstance(mContext, mIsTablet, (int)mClient.getID(), sessionId);
                // Replace the old fragment with the new one
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();                   
                ft.replace(R.id.client_list, details);
                ft.addToBackStack("client_list");
                // Use a fade animation. This makes it clear that this is not a new "layer"
                // above the current, but a replacement
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);                            

      ft.commit();
              ...
              //now add another fragment to the right, just to test i dont have my invoice fragment done yet so I just added session again to see if it would display it does.

SessionEdit details2 = (SessionEdit) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.session_edit);              

                // Make new fragment instance to show the recipe
                details2 = SessionEdit.newInstance(mContext, mIsTablet, (int)mClient.getID(), sessionId);
                // Replace the old fragment with the new one
                FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft2.replace(R.id.client_details, details2);
                ft.addToBackStack("client_details");
                // Use a fade animation. This makes it clear that this is not a new "layer"
                // above the current, but a replacement
                ft2.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);                           

      ft2.commit();
 ...
}
```

This works well, though i realized that I was replacing not the `"div"` so to speak on the layout but the fragment itself, so my references to `findFragmentById` were no longer my `client_details` type or `client_list` type but now a `SessionEdit` type.  So after more trial and error i learned to add the tag to `addToBackStack(tag)` and I could find fragmentsByTag now, this worked well, and back button sorta worked:  Clicking back would replace my client_list on the left again so I could click clients and get their details on the right, the problem is, if my client_list was back again the details on the right would still show my session fragment.  Also another issue is my clients list was a `ListFragment`, so when I did the replace, I could still see the list like underneath the new fragment, as if it was celluloid or something.  Very strange.

So I made some headway on replacing my original fragments with new ones, but navigating using the back button no longer works "out of the box" like it did when I was just doing the two fragments, and adding new activities onto each other.  So how does one go about navigating around multiple fragments? Ideally I would have a SessionInvoiceActivity that would replace both fragments at once (The client list on left, client details on right) with the session on left, invoices on right.  And when the backbutton is clicked, id get back to my client list and client details?  But this I am not sure how to do and still pass in the information I need.  I am also still not clear as to why when I replace the fragment, the original fragment can be seen underneath?  Is it a xml layout definition issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have figured this out now, seems I am a summer behind.

I found fragments specified in layouts (in XML) and fragments added with the FragmentManager are difficult to mix.

I am having a similar issue being I add my "Master" Fragment in onCreate(), then when deemed necessary through size or user selection a second fragment the "Details" Fragment is either put where the "Master" Fragment was or is added to a second layout if it is in landscape mode. When the user hits the Back Key it will show a blank screen with no "Master" Fragment. I thought I may have had a work around for this by making the original call to display my "Master" Fragment in the onStart() of the Activity. Yet there seems to be one more gotcha to this. When adding the "Master" Fragment from the onStart() DO NOT add the transaction to the BackStack. That way the onResume() or whatever from your previous Activity will be called instead, thus not leaving an Activity with a blank screen.